# When can 1-forms be written as the differential of a coordinate map?

Tags: differential-geometry

So it is well known that given a smooth vector field $X$ on a smooth manifold $M$, at each point $p\in M$ we can find coordinates $(U,x)$ such that $X = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}$ in these coordinates.

My question is, does there exist a similar statement for $1$-forms? i.e, given a one form $\omega \in \Omega^1(M)$, does there exist a chart $(U,x)$ around $p$ so that $\omega = dx^1$.

At the moment I'm unsure but I'm leaning towards it not being true in general.

So far I have that if $\ker\omega$ is integrable locally around $p$, then I feel this is sufficient for the existence of such a chart, since we can just take the frobenius chart and scale it as necessary. However, a counterexample or proof for the general case eludes me.

Any help to clear this up for me is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the form is not closed, then it cannot be of that form (and if it is closed,  then its kernel is involutive and you can use Frobenius's theorem.)

Comment: Thanks! we haven't really talked about closed/exact yet but this let me find a counterexample like I was after.